# I am trying to get the value from sx:autocompleter in order to reset the value using javascript depending upon some conditions

Tags: javascript, jquery, dojo

my code in jsp page is as follows

```
<td><sx:autocompleter id="select1" name="select1" href="%fruitlist" /></td>
```

now i want to get the value entered in this and validate in my script portion using javascript. i was trying dojo.widget.byId("select1") but did not get proper resolution. suggest me plz..

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the selected value of the autocompleter dropdown, you can use

```
var vname=dojo.widget.byId('select1').getValue();
```